# One table not display on phpmyadmin left panel

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am curious why one of the table "cars" is not listed on the left panel of the phpMyAdmin. Maybe I did something "wrong" but I can't seem to locate and undo it.

[Table 'cars' not listed (left panel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eR3G.png)

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

You've hidden the display of the "cars" table, as indicated by the eye icon next to the "sample" database label. The same icon showing that a table is hidden opens the dialog to show that table:

[image: Icon to show hidden tables]

Clicking the icon brings up the "show hidden icon" dialog from which you can show the missing items:

[image: Show table dialog]

---

You can hide tables with the eyeball icon next to a visible table:

[image: How to hide]